# How to securely wipe all data from iOS device prior to sale

Tags: ios, secure-erase

Ive got a couple of iPads that i no longer use that i wish to sell on eBay.

They run a range of iOS versions from iOS 9-12

What steps should i take to make sure that data, passwords, photos, accounts etc stored on the iPad are secure and not recoverable once the device is with a 3rd party.

Comment: [What to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201351)

Comment: There's many questions about erasing devices already on this site.  Have you tried any of those answers?  If so, which did not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Settings > General > Erase All Content and Settings` is the [Apple method](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351) for preparing your iDevice for sale or giveaway.

*Steps below lifted entirely from the Apple support page linked above.*

#### What to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch

1. If you paired an Apple Watch with your iPhone, unpair your Apple Watch.
2. Back up your device.
3. Sign out of iCloud and the iTunes & App Store.

   - If you're using iOS 10.3 or later, tap Settings > [your name]. Scroll down and tap Sign Out. Enter your Apple ID password and tap Turn Off.
   - If you're using iOS 10.2 or earlier, tap Settings > iCloud > Sign Out. Tap Sign Out again, then tap Delete from My [device] and enter your Apple ID password. Then go to Settings > iTunes & App Store > Apple ID > Sign Out.
4. Go back to Settings and tap General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings. If you turned on Find My iPhone, you might need to enter your Apple ID and password.
5. If asked for your device passcode or Restrictions passcode, enter it. Then tap Erase [device].
6. If you're switching to a non-Apple phone, deregister iMessage.
7. Contact your carrier for help transferring service to a new owner. If you aren't using a SIM card with your device, you can contact them to get help transferring service to the new owner.